#  numeric formatting "R" in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, number-formatting

I'm using Json.NET to output a notepad-readable JSON file.  The output is nearly perfect, except very small numbers (-0.000004) are converted to scientific notation.  This is not my intention.

I downloaded the sources and in JsonConvert.cs - JsonConvert.ToString(double), I see the line:

```
value.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

According to C# numeric formatting documentation, "R" should guarantee a round-trip, not convert to scientific notation, but it does.  I changed the format string to `"0.############"` and it works great.  But is this the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that yes, "0.############" is the right approach because it works, it's easy to understand, and according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString), the Round-Trip format may or may not use scientific notation. The only guarantee is that "a numeric value that is converted to a string will be parsed back into the same numeric value." I see nothing about not using scientific notation.

If you want it to always be a specific number of digits, then you could use the [Fixed Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString) format.

```
value.ToString("F8"); // will be 8 digits
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general purpose library, I think JSON.NET is doing the right thing using the round-trip format. This ensures that no information is lost. From a practical point of view, scientific notation can be much shorter than decimal notation (`1e-200` would require more than 200 characters), so again, it seems like this approach to implementing a round-trip format is the right thing to do.

Having said that, your use is also entirely valid. However, changing the source code of a 3rd party library comes with its own problems. Any time you get a new JSON.NET version, you have to apply the same change. At some point, the internal workings of the library might change and then this fix would no longer work.

In my view, it is best to work with what you have if you can. In this case you can write a custom converter and apply a [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) attribute to your property. It's really easy to do: The existing date/time converters should give you a head start.